# Amazon S3 accessing data from single url ( not presigned )

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an url of this shape : `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/team.example.com/filename.json`

When accessing the url I get the following response :

```html
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>5NSY1BMKCPV9DPPV</RequestId>
<HostId>MEq7411VPUTNck6EXKa+vudqavjYMAXTGPlSIdtsUB2ckU5329xEfPuGHvKKeiCkml1J707vE2w=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've been fighting with AWS for some time now to get an answer, but I'm not sure. I get the feeling I need a presigned url, as I don't have access to this url.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can be a lot of issues - yes you would need a presigned URL to gain access to this object or change the bucket/object permissions. Is this your bucket?

Comment: No this is not mine. This is sent by a trusted third party to review the data in it.

Comment: They need to provide you with a pre-signed URL or access to the bucket. If they want you to just download the file to review, a pre-signed URL would be best.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot ! That was my first though, but i'm too new to AWS to be sure about that by myself.

Comment: Yes - loads of questions out there or tutorials. Enjoy using AWS!

Comment: Did you ask the trusted third-party how to access the file they shared?

Comment: Turns out they didn't send the correct file !